# Powershell populate array from list of files

Tags: arrays, powershell

I need to populate a powershell array with the filenames of files stored in a directory based on their names. I need a different array for each set of files  (see Example folder structure) to be used as part of another process.

I would like this to be automatic and create the arrays on the fly, so I would have arrays containing all the filenames starting with `processor123`, another for `processorabc` and `processorxyz`. The names of these arrays can be stored in another array named `$arrynames`. It needs to be dynamic in case a new processor is introduced, I do not want to rely on users to enter the file names.

**Example folder structure;**

```
c:\directory\processor123\processor123.log.20150604
c:\directory\processor123\processor123.log.20150603
c:\directory\processor123\processor123.log.20150602
c:\directory\processor123\processor123.log.20150601
c:\directory\processor123\processor123.log.20150531
c:\directory\processorabc.log.20150604
c:\directory\processorabc.log.20150603
c:\directory\processorabc.log.20150602
c:\directory\processorabc.log.20150601
c:\directory\processorabc.log.20150531
c:\directory\processorxyz.log.20150604
c:\directory\processorxyz.log.20150603
c:\directory\processorxyz.log.20150602
c:\directory\processorxyz.log.20150601
c:\directory\processorxyz.log.20150531
```

**$ArryNames**

```
processor123
processorabc
processorxyz
```

**$processor123**

```
c:\directory\processor123\processor123.log.20150604
c:\directory\processor123\processor123.log.20150603
c:\directory\processor123\processor123.log.20150602
c:\directory\processor123\processor123.log.20150601
c:\directory\processor123\processor123.log.20150531
```

**$processorabc**

```
c:\directory\processorabc.log.20150604
c:\directory\processorabc.log.20150603
c:\directory\processorabc.log.20150602
c:\directory\processorabc.log.20150601
c:\directory\processorabc.log.20150531
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Ive tried a couple of things but nothing works, I'm pretty new to the scripting world

Comment: Even if you're "new", you should have posted some code in your question indicating that you have tried something. What you ask for is doable, although I say you'd better not go with a variable named `$processorabc`, as it's pretty hard to refer a variable by its name. Instead, you might want to use `$sometable["processor123"]`. If there would be a "processor" named `ArryNames`, you'll be screwed, but using a hash table will still work, you'll just get a `$sometable["ArryNames"] and no breaking of the script.

Comment: Ok, apologies, thanks for the heads up on hash tables, I will work on this, looks promising.

Comment: @Vesper Not only to indicate that he tried something, but to help the rest of us a) avoid wasting time on things he already tried and/or b) point out potential mistakes in his previous attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you'll want to do for each string:

1. Extract first part of file name
2. Put entire string into array matching the first part

As already mentioned in comments, you can use a hashtable to hold the arrays, with the file prefix being the key:

```
# Set up a hashtable
$HashTable = @{}

# Pipe your list of file paths to ForEach-Object
Get-Content C:\filenames.txt |ForEach-Object {
    # Extract the filename with [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName(), split it by dots and grab only the part before the first dot
    $Prefix = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_) -split "\." |Select-Object -First 1
    # Use the extracted prefix to place the string in the correct hashtable entry
    $HashTable[$Prefix] += $_
}
```

Now, you can reference the first 5 paths with: `$HashTable["processor123"]`

Comment: you sir are a genius, That works exactly as desired. Having never used hash tables before this is all new to me, thankyou for adding all the comments as well.